# Getting blank string in following DOMDocument program

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, domdocument, emoji

I've a following program which replaces the `<img>` tags present in a HTML strings by some code. But I'm not understanding why I'm getting blank string after completing the string processing. I'm not able to point out the mistake even after deep debugging, so asking for someone's help.

If you look at my program I've put in comments with the output at important steps just to make you understand quickly and save your precious time.

```
<?php
  function string_sanitizer($feed_status) { 
    /*echo $feed_status.PHP_EOL;
<img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" /><img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" /><img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" />*/

    $temp = $feed_status;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($feed_status, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    /*print_r($imageTags);
      echo PHP_EOL;        
    DOMNodeList Object
    (
        [length] => 3
    )*/
    $replacements = array(
      'evilgrin.png' => '\ue404',
      'grin.png' => '\ue415',
      'happy.png' => '\ue057',
      'smile.png' => '\ue056',
      'surprised.png' => '\ue107',
      'tongue.png' => '\ue105',
      'unhappy.png' => '\ue403',
      'waii.png' => '\ue407',
      'wink.png' => '\ue405',
    );

    // regression 
    $i = $imageTags->length - 1;
    /*echo "Value of i:".$i.PHP_EOL;
      Value of i:2*/     
    while($i > -1) { 
      //echo "Loop Counter :".$i.PHP_EOL;

      $tag = $imageTags->item($i);
      /*print_r($tag);
      echo PHP_EOL;*/
      $basename = basename($tag->getAttribute('src'));
      //echo $basename.PHP_EOL;
      if(isset($replacements[$basename])) { //echo "In a loop :".$i.PHP_EOL; 
        //if the file name matches make replacements
        $r = $replacements[$basename];
        //echo "Value of r : ".$r.PHP_EOL;
        $text = $doc->createTextNode($r);
        /*print_r($text);
        echo PHP_EOL;*/ 
        $tag->parentNode->replaceChild($text, $tag);
        /*print_r($tag);
        echo PHP_EOL;*/
      }
      $i--;
    }
    //I think till here everything works fine but issue is in saving this HTML

    // append to string container again
    $feed_status = '';
    foreach($doc->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes as $e) {
      $feed_status .= addslashes($doc->saveHTML($e));
    }   

      echo "Final feed status :".$feed_status; die;


    if($feed_status == '') {
      $feed_status = strip_tags($temp);        
    }
    return $feed_status;
  }

$str_sample = '<img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" /><img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" /><img src="http://54.174.50.242/file/pic/emoticon/default/smile.png" alt="Smile" title="Smile" title="v_middle" />';
$jumbo = string_sanitizer($str_sample);
echo $jumbo;
?>
```

I don't understand why I'm getting blank string after at the end of processing instead of  a string **"\ue056\ue056\ue056"**

Please help me in this issue. I think the code works fine but issue is in saving this changed HTML. Please help me.

Comment: Are you going to completely replace a `src` attribute with its corresponding replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Put your `$feed_status` HTML fragment inside some wrapper tag pair when creating the DOMDocument object:

```
@$doc->loadHTML('<div>' . $feed_status . '</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Output with above adjustment applied:

```
Final feed status :\\ue056\\ue056\\ue056
```